# Build Errors when installing openfeint 2.4.4 SDK

Tags: iphone, openfeint

I have 12 build errors when trying to install the openFeint SDK.

Build Invisible_Pong of project rocket_pong with configuration Debug

```
Ld "build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Invisible Pong.app/Invisible Pong" normal i386
cd /Users/robkwok/Documents/rocket_pong
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.5
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator3.0.sdk -L/Users/robkwok/Documents/rocket_pong/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/robkwok/Documents/rocket_pong/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist "/Users/robkwok/Documents/rocket_pong/build/rocket_pong.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Invisible_Pong.build/Objects-normal/i386/Invisible Pong.LinkFileList" -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -lobjc -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3 -o "/Users/robkwok/Documents/rocket_pong/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Invisible Pong.app/Invisible Pong"

Undefined symbols:
  ".objc_class_name_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocationManager in OFLocation.o
  ".objc_class_name_CLLocation", referenced from:
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocation in OFHighScoreAnnotation.o
      literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@CLLocation in OFHighScoreMapViewController.o
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainSystemConfiguration", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainSystemConfiguration$non_lazy_ptr in OFAsyncSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain$non_lazy_ptr in OFCRVStompClient.o
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainNetDB$non_lazy_ptr in OFAsyncSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings$non_lazy_ptr in OFAsyncSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainNetServices", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainNetServices$non_lazy_ptr in OFAsyncSocket.o
  "_kCLLocationAccuracyBest", referenced from:
      _kCLLocationAccuracyBest$non_lazy_ptr in OFLocation.o
  "_kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot$non_lazy_ptr in OFCRVStompClient.o
  "_kCFStreamErrorDomainMach", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamErrorDomainMach$non_lazy_ptr in OFAsyncSocket.o
  "_kCFStreamSSLLevel", referenced from:
      _kCFStreamSSLLevel$non_lazy_ptr in OFCRVStompClient.o
  ".objc_class_name_MKAnnotationView", referenced from:
      .objc_class_name_OFHighScoreAnnotationView in OFHighScoreAnnotationView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's what I've done so far:

1. Unzipped the openFeint folder and dragged it into my project
2. Added the appropriate frameworks  (including libsqlite3.dylib)
3. Added #import "openFeintPrefix.pch" to my APP_prefix.pch

Answer (score 12):

You have to include the CoreLocation, CFNetwork and MapKit frameworks also.

Comment: Don't forget to mark Kenny's answer as Correct, so he gets teh reputation credit (like he needs it! ;)

Also, the integration instructions for the latest OF are pretty good, and include a full list of required frameworks.